# AutoMapper - include/replace a single item in source list while mapping back with ReverseMap()

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

My current map:

```
CreateMap<Item, ItemDetailsViewModel>()
  .ForMember(x => x.ActiveChildItem, d => d.MapFrom(z => z.ChildItems.FirstOrDefault(f => f.IsActive)))
  .ReverseMap()
  .ForMember(x => x.ChildItems, d => /*How I can find and replace item in source list 
                                                        items(ChildItems) to ActiveChildItem?*/)
```

What is the best way to do a map from a single item to item collection? 
I don't want to use a collection in my view model...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, that is not a mapping operation. It is something you should perform when the property mappings are done.

Use the `AfterMap` method for this -

```
CreateMap<Item, ItemDetailsViewModel>()
  .ForMember(x => x.ActiveChildItem, d => d.MapFrom(z => z.ChildItems.FirstOrDefault(f => f.IsActive)))
  .ReverseMap()
  .AfterMap((s, d) =>
    {
        // add or find-and-replace child item here
    });
```

Or,

```
CreateMap<Item, ItemDetailsViewModel>()
  .ForMember(x => x.ActiveChildItem, d => d.MapFrom(z => z.ChildItems.FirstOrDefault(f => f.IsActive)))
  .ReverseMap()
  .AfterMap<MyCoolAction>();
```

where `MyCoolAction` is an implementation of `IMappingAction`, like -

```
public class MyCoolAction : IMappingAction<ItemVM, Item>
{
    public void Process(ItemVM source, Item destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        // add or find-and-replace child item here
    }
}
```

For more, check the documentation - [Before and After Map Action](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Before-and-after-map-actions.html#before-and-after-map-action)

Answer (score 0):

Having a *complete example* would make it much easier to help you. Also there is one point you didn't consider.

What should happen when you map back from the single item back to the collection? Should the collection be replaced by a new collection with a single item? Should the existing list be altered and what happens if you alter the list, but the view model item can't be found in the model list. Should it be added?

So regardless to these open question, below is an example on how you could replace the entire list.

If you need a different behaviour take a look into the last `CreateMap()` method. The third parameter `dest` points to the current property value of the destination object. So it contains the model list. Instead of returning a value (like I did with the new list), you could manipulate the existing `dest` list by your needs.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using AutoMapper;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(conf => conf.AddProfile<MyProfile>());
            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

            var model = new Model { Items = new[] { new ModelItem { Name = "NotActive Item", IsActive = false }, new ModelItem { Name = "Active Item", IsActive = true } } };

            var viewModel = mapper.Map<ViewModel>(model);
            var newModel = mapper.Map<Model>(viewModel);

            Console.WriteLine(viewModel.ActiveItem.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(newModel.Items.Count);
            Console.WriteLine(newModel.Items.First().Name);
            Console.WriteLine(newModel.Items.First().IsActive);
        }
    }

    public class MyProfile : Profile
    {
        public MyProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<ModelItem, ViewModelItem>();
            CreateMap<Model, ViewModel>()
                .ForMember(view => view.ActiveItem, conf => conf.MapFrom(model => model.Items.FirstOrDefault(item => item.IsActive)));

            CreateMap<ViewModelItem, ModelItem>().ForMember(item => item.IsActive, conf => conf.MapFrom(_ => true));
            CreateMap<ViewModel, Model>()
                .ForMember(model => model.Items, conf => conf.MapFrom((view, model, dest, context) => view.ActiveItem == null
                                                                                                    ? Array.Empty<ModelItem>()
                                                                                                    : new[] { context.Mapper.Map<ModelItem>(view.ActiveItem) }));
        }
    }

    public class Model
    {
        public IReadOnlyList<ModelItem> Items { get; set; }
    }

    public class ModelItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }

    public class ViewModel
    {
        public ViewModelItem ActiveItem { get; set; }
    }


    public class ViewModelItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```